# A potentially recoverable error occured in Google Sign-In iOS SDK

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, google-signin

I integrated new Google Sign-In SDK 2.4.0 in  my application. I am trying to login with Google, getting below error message

```
A potentially recoverable error occured. You can try again.
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with Bundle Id Mismatch

Both  your project bundle id and google sign in bundle id should be same.

When it asks for your iOS Bundle Id, make sure it matches the bundle id that you find in your Xcode project settings (target -> General -> Bundle Identifier)

Delete the old "GoogleService-Info.plist" file and replace it with the new one you just created

clean, try to sign in again.

Comment: Hi @Uma Madhavi, It is working in iOS 9.2 device, not in iOS 9.1. I am using xcode 6.4